# Jquery click event fire twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am building something with Jquery, and I am making some Ajax calls. So after my ajax calls, I need to call functions to trace clicks on some elements again. Here an example of such a function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initSomething();
});
function initSomething(){
    $('.something').click(function(){
        alert('hello');
    });
}
```

And now an ajax function:

```
$('#AddSomething').click(function(){
    $.post('somewhere.php',{data},function(data){
        initSomething();
    });
});
```

And the problem is: I feel like when I initSomething(); for the second time, it's like it's readding a click event on the elements already traced by the first initSomething called on document ready.

So I tried something like e.preventDefault and e.preventPropagation(), but it doesn't seem to work, what am I missing?

Thanks for your answers and have a nice day!

**EDIT: As saw on the answers, I forgot to say that the Ajax call is inserting new .something elements in the DOM...**

**EDIT 2: Here a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wpsnz7op/**

Comment: Does ths changes anything? 

    function initSomething(){
        $('.something').off('click');
        $('.something').click(function(){
            alert('hello');
        });
    }

Comment: May `#Addsomething` and `.something` be the same element or one is the child of the other?

Comment: To clarify - do you add **new** `.something` elements during the ajax call that you need to also attach the click handler to?

Comment: The best thing for us to help you will be if you provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Exactly, a new .something is inserted in the DOM with the ajax call

Comment: use **.off()** jquery api to remoe the click event and then re assign the event like '$('#item').of('click').on('click',function(){ });'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) api to remove the already attached event and reassign the event like following.

```
function initSomething(){
    $('.something').off('click').click(function(){
        alert('hello');
    });
}
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: Well, it is working great! Thanks! And it's the solution that helps me best keep my actual code...

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to rebind clicks from what I can see of the code you have there.

Just do not rebind and you will not have a multiple click issue.

Comment: Then should use event delegation with `.on` instead. The way the question is written it is very hard to tell what is going on here... :-(

Answer (score -1):

Use event delegation instead of that.

```
 $(document).on('click','.something',function(){
        alert('hello');
    });
```

Then there is no need for calling the `initSomething();` function after ajax.

Comment: How does this answer the question? There will **still** be multiple click events handled on one object.

Comment: @Neal user is trying to bind the event again,. Probably it should be for the new elements created after ajax.

Comment: this would be proper approach, not sure why it got down voted. Explanation could be improved though

Comment: ^^ This.  I'd +1 this if it explained why, and especially explained why you should remove the subsequent calls to `initSomething()`, and why.  As it is this will make no sense to someone that would ask the question.